# Как сохранить веб страницу страницу автоматически?

Tags: windows

Как сохранить страницу автоматически. Есть вот такой батник
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://www.yandex.ru/
На страницу я попадаю как теперь её сохранить:?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: http-клиент используйте. wget/curl/w3m/aria2/links/lynx и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: https://github.com/Y2Z/monolith ?